# which form design is better?

Tags: usability, forms

I have been working on a medium sized form. I have developed a few options. I have read various UX articles. Many people advise against multi column forms -
 but if I go by this approach, the user will have to scroll a lot to fill up the fields and also it may not look good. Hence I have developed a few prototypes. Please advise, which of the following is right approach in terms of looks as well as usability? If none of these is good, what should be the approach that does not waste much space on the screen and does not need the user to scroll much, but at the same time user-friendly and looks good?

**Form 1**

[image]

**Form 2**

[image]

Comment: Is the platform mobile/tablet or desktop?

Comment: @UXfrom12 It's desktop

Comment: NB4's answer works then. Scrolling isn't so much of an issue, the usual UX recommendation applies, only collect data which is useful; forcing people to complete data inputs that have no relevance to the application is a poor experience.

Comment: @UXfrom12 does my "Form1" follow the approach you recommended? Basically, I am worried that if I stack all sections in a sigle column, much of the GUI screen will remain empty. Does that look good?

Comment: No, the answer below makes sense.

Comment: It is better for the users to scroll rather than search through the columns to find something.

Comment: @Saptarshi I clearly agree with UXfrom12 & Kristiyan Lukanov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form looks better when it's categorized. Grouping related fields together also helps users make sense of the information that they must fill in.

[image]

For reference: https://uxplanet.org/designing-more-efficient-forms-structure-inputs-labels-and-actions-e3a47007114f

Comment: does my "Form1" follow the approach you recommended?

Comment: Yes. It does follow the approach as mentioned in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the advise from Uxdesign.com

https://uxdesign.cc/design-better-forms-96fadca0f49c